# ReactPlayer make auto play

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I try to make video player in reactjs

Here my code

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";\

function App() {
  const [myvideo, setMyvideo] = useState("");
  const arrayqueue = [
    {
      singer: "The Valley",
      videoname: "video/video_test.mp4",
    },
    {
      singer: "My Friend",
      videoname: "video/video_test2.mp4",
    },
    {
      singer: "Say wow",
      videoname: "video/video_test3.mp4",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactPlayer url={myvideo} controls={true} />
      <div className="queue-size" id="style-1">
        {arrayqueue.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="row-queue"
              key={index}
              onClick={() => setMyvideo(item.videoname)}
            >
              <div className="column-queue">{item.singer}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm sucess make onclick in the queue and set video to ReactPlayer , my question is how to make ReactPlayer automatic play the next from queue , so the ReactPlayer have 2 option , if I don't click in queue , the video will autoplay from queue, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ReactPlayer** has a prop called `onEnded` ([more info here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player#callback-props)) that can be used to trigger a callback function when the current media finishes playing.

You could keep track of the index for the video that is currently playing and set a callback to loop through your array of videos.

I updated your code and added comments to the lines I changed, so you can see an example:

```js
import "./App.css";
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";\

function App() {
  const [myvideo, setMyvideo] = useState("");

  // New state to save index of currently playing video
  const [myvideoIndex, setMyvideoIndex] = useState(0);

  const arrayqueue = [
    {
      singer: "The Valley",
      videoname: "video/video_test.mp4",
    },
    {
      singer: "My Friend",
      videoname: "video/video_test2.mp4",
    },
    {
      singer: "Say wow",
      videoname: "video/video_test3.mp4",
    },
  ];

  // Callback function that plays next video (or goes back to first video)
  const playNext = () => {
    const nextIndex = myvideoIndex + 1
    if (nextIndex >= arrayqueue.length) {
      setMyvideo(arrayqueue[0])
      setMyvideoIndex(0)
    } else {
      setMyvideo(arrayqueue[nextIndex])
      setMyvideoIndex(nextIndex)
    }
  }

  // When click, set the video and the current index
  const handleClick = (item, index) => {
    setMyvideo(item.videoname)
    setMyvideoIndex(index)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactPlayer url={myvideo} controls={true} onEnded={playNext} />
      <div className="queue-size" id="style-1">
        {arrayqueue.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="row-queue"
              key={index}
              onClick={() => handleClick(item, index)}
            >
              <div className="column-queue">{item.singer}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```